# Vector-valued differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-bundles

Given a smooth real manifold $M$, and a real vector space $V$, when we talk about a $V$-valued $k$-form on $M$, do we mean an element of $\Gamma(\wedge^{*k}M)\otimes V$, where $\Gamma$ denotes sections of a vector bundle and $\wedge^{*k}M$ is the $k$th exterior bundle, or do we actually mean there is a $\pi:V\rightarrow M$ vector bundle, and a $V$-valued $k$-form is an element of $\Gamma(\wedge^{*k}M\otimes V)$?

Basically, if we take a $V$-valued $k$-form, and we will in its arguments, then will the resulting object be the element of a "global" vector space that is completely independent of the manifold, or will it be a "field", which at point $p$ has its value in $V_p$ that is **distinct** from $V_q$?

Also the prior question might be badly worded in the sense that I can totally imagine a $V$-valued $k$-form depend on points of the manifold after its arguments are all plugged in, what I am mainly curious about is that *is it possible to compare the value of a vector-valued $k$-form at point $p$ with its value at point $q$*?

Comment: Your second guess is correct.

Comment: It's really ambiguous given your language. If you specify that $V$ is a vector space, rather than a vector bundle on $M$, then you get the first case. Otherwise you should be calling it a vector bundle-valued differential form. If you really are dealing with a vector bundle, then of course you'll need a connection to start "comparing" values at different points. But I don't know what you imagine in your last paragraph, because how you need to know how to relate the vectors you plug into your $k$-form at different points, regardless.

Comment: @TedShifrin Okay, more specific scenario then: Given a principal $G$-bundle and a connection on it, we tend to encounter $\mathfrak{g}$-valued differential forms. In that case, do we actually have a vector bundle, whose fibers are $\mathfrak{g}$, and the difform takes values in that, or do we have an "outside" Lie-algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and the difform takes values in that?

Comment: @Uldreth: I'm not answering because Andreas and Daniel did such a thorough job in their answers. You might want to take a look at Chern/Chen/Lam's Lectures on Differential Geometry. Chern's style, albeit not to everyone's taste, is more hands-on than most differential geometry treatments.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that there is a uniform use of terminology, although it seems more common to me that "vector valued differential forms" refers to the case of a fixed vector space, whereas in the other case, I would use the terminology "vector bundle valued differential forms". An important difference between the two cases is that in the former case, there is a natural version of the exterior derivative, while in the latter case, one has to choose a linear connection on the vector bundle in order to have an analog of the exterior derivative.

The case of $\mathfrak g$-valued forms on a principal bundle you mention in your comment is the case of a fixed vector space (and if you define connection forms in that way, you need the exterior derivative on vector valued forms in the definition of curvature). Principal bundles also provide a nice relation between the two cases: Suppose $P\to M$ is a principal $G$-bundle, $V$ is a representation of $G$ (so in particular a finite dimensional vector space). Then there is a the associated vector bundle $E=P\times_G V\to M$ and one can identify the space $\Omega^*(M,E)$ of vector bundle valued forms with a subspace of the space $\Omega^*(P,V)$ of vector valued differential forms. The elements in that subspace are exactly those forms, which are horizontal and $P$-equivariant.

Comment: I see, thank you. Can you give me some book recommendations on the subject? I already know Kobayashi & Nomizu and Spivak's multivolume grimoirs, and whilst I have utilized both prior, K&N is sometimes very hard to understand, and Spivak is too caught up in trying to make a transition between modern treatments and old-school treatments, it gets way too sprawling and talkative at times.

Comment: I'd also appreciate having a global/invariant discussion of riemannian curvature in terms of forms. Physics texts often have that, but they just replace christoffel-symbols with connection forms, that in that context are just as frame-dependant. So I'd like a frame-independant formulation/discussion which also tells how to move between the two pictures and maybe has some example calculations.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, usually "vector valued differential form" refers to a differential form with values in a vector bundle, so let
$$E\longrightarrow M$$
be a vector bundle, then the space of $V$-valued $k$ forms is
$$\Omega^k(M;E) = \Gamma(\Lambda^kT^*M\otimes V).$$
Notice that you can recover the first case you present simply by taking the trivial bundle $E=M\times V$ for $V$ a vector space, and in that case people often abuse of notation and speak of $V$-valued forms meaning $(M\times V)$-valued forms.

---

As people are talking about gauge theory, both situations are encountered in that context. For example, (principal) connections on a principal $G$-bundle $P$ over $M$ can be represented by some $\mathfrak{g}$-valued $1$-forms. The space of connections is an affine space, and its tangent space at a connection $A$ is given by
$$T_A\mathcal{A} = \Omega^1(M;\text{ad}P),$$
where $\text{ad}P$ is the vector bundle over $M$ obtained by taking the quotient of $P\times\mathfrak{g}$ by the relation
$$(p\cdot g,\xi)\sim(p,\text{ad}_g\xi).$$